# Youtube API upload duration too short

Tags: c#, video, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm trying to upload videos with c#, the upload itself works **but**

the videos are always too short (e.g. a 2:14 video becomes a 00:29 video in youtube, a 00:45 video becomes a 00:05 video).

I get no error messages or exceptions during the upload

Here's the code I'm using

```
        UserCredential credential;
        ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets();
        secrets.ClientId = "clientid";
        secrets.ClientSecret = "clientsecret";
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            secrets,
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            "username", 
            CancellationToken.None
        );

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });

        var video = new Video();
        video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
        video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
        video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
        video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
        video.Status = new VideoStatus();
        video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
        var filePath = @"filepath";
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet, status", fileStream, "video/mp4");

            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
            videosInsertRequest.Upload();
        }
```

To codes is derived from a google-api example

Comment: Sounds like the Video you are uploading has got either a varying or a very low framerate. Can you also post some Infos about the Video you are uploading, e.g. the Output of mediainfo?

Comment: Sure, duration: 02:14; bitrate: 1300kb; fps: 29. What else do you need?

Comment: You might already know if you have constant framerate or not... but anyway i ask before remaining silent: What does mediainfo tell you about Frame rate mode and FrameRate_Mode_Original - and can you post a link to your uploaded Video?

Comment: Sorry but where do I find the Mediainfo?

Comment: Sorry too, i always assume that anyone dealing with Video stuff already knows it: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download

Comment: The framerate in the uploaded video is similar to the original video. When I download the uploaded video I get the shortened version aswell so the issue has to be tackled in the upload

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157845/discussion-between-john-smith-and-harry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By transcoding the Video using ffmpeg commandline:

- ffmpeg -i %source% %target%.mp4

we found out using mediainfo

- http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download

that the Output from ffmpeg was Shorter than the original. ffmpeg Output did indicate some error Messages about non-found NAL Units which means the Input stream is scrambeled and the uploaded Video was actually Shorter than VLC media Player Shows.